# May I use Adobe Reader in commercial use?

Tags: html, adobe, licensing

I want to create a pdf manipulating app and forshowing I use a html file with the pdf. I read that Adobe Reader is a "Free Licensed Software".

So May I use Adobe Reader for the Viewing for free or do I have to buy a License ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Reader is a free licensed software (but not open).

See the license agreement at http://www.adobe.com/products/eulas/pdfs/Reader10_combined-20100625_1419.pdf - you may need to select your language from the bookmarks on the left.

If you want to distribute Adobe Reader within your organization, you may need to obtain a distribution agreement; see http://get.adobe.com/reader/enterprise/

If you have more detailed questions regarding licensing, this forum may be able to help you: http://forums.adobe.com/community/licensing

Source:
https://forums.adobe.com/message/4396120